# How to manage multiple coredata MOC while sharing it with App Extension?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext, ios-app-extension

Am facing a semaphore issue in my application randomly, can this be due to coredata locking the main thread? The coredata context is being used as below:
App 
 1. Main context(Main Queue) that deals with UI and every CRUD operation.
 2. Private Context(private queue with main context as parent) used in NSOperation subclass to sync data to and from cloud kit.

Both the context share a single persistentstore coordinator.

Extension
 1. Main context(main queue) with its own persistent store co-ordinator.

This all context can be live at a time. How can i best manage them without losing data and causing deadlocks.

Note: Have debugged using the coredata concurrency variable. This is my first time with coredata any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, what is your question? Do have some code that you can share? These are some fundamentals when using Stack to help you and the rest of the community.

Comment: Hi have edited the question to best describe my scenarios. Any help is appreciated.